# android start Video recording upon starting an activity

Tags: android

android start Video recording upon starting an activity without using buttons ,ie when the activity starts video recording also should start without using any other component,its working with buttons,i tried putting video calling functions in onCreate,onStart() etc
any idea any one

Comment: why didn't it work in onCreate what happens?

Comment: doesn't it sound like security issue?

Comment: i think the recording is starting but not displaying in the video view(in onStart()), ie if i stop and start the recording manaully its working,but not when the activity begins or onstartup

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with recording a video, but when working with the camera I often had the problem that some variables like a surfaceHolder aren't initialized until you can actually see the surface. So if you see the button, the surface will be there too and thus everything works. If you try to do it instantly in onCreate something might still be null and so recording won't work. You could try and find out if this is the case.